# Microsoft Excel 2007 ignores / resets margins, are there any "known issue" fixes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

I have an .xlsx file that I fill in automatically in C#. If I open the resulting file on a system with Office 2016, the custom margins and other print options are intact. Office 2007 though resets them to some default, making it not fit on the page when printing anymore.

Comment: Sometimes terminating all Excel processes then restarting will fix buggy page setup behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an exact official article to explain this phenomenon, but lower versions of word are not compatible with files generated by higher versions of word.

I recommend that these files be saved in the "word 97 - 2003" format.

[image]